# How to make a matrix from two arrays column and rows in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have a json data format:
`[{'note':'n1','subject':'subject1','value':10},{'note':'n3','subject':'subject2','value':19}];`
from that I have generate two arrays one for header column `cols` and other for row `rows`

```js
let notes = [{'note':'n1','subject':'subject1','value':10},{'note':'n3','subject':'subject2','value':19}];

let cols = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'];
let rows = ['subject1', 'subject2'];

let matrix = Array(cols.length).fill(Array(rows.length).fill(0));
for(const x of notes){
    let {note, subject, value} = x;
    matrix[cols.indexOf(note)][rows.indexOf(subject)] = note;
}
console.log(matrix)
```

Expected result:

```
[[10,0,0],[0,0,19]]
```

But My goal is to render it as an `HTML` table looks like this:

| Subj\Note | Note1 | Note2 | Note3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Subj1 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| subj2 | 0 | 0 | 19 |

How could I do that, Any suggestion or help is much appreciated!

Comment: That's not JSON. That's just a Javascript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just a few points:

- Your intention is to declare and create a 2D array but that's not actually the case
- You have `rows` and `columns` mixed up
- Instead of `= note` you should have `= value`.

```js
let notes = [{'note':'n1','subject':'subject1','value':10},{'note':'n3','subject':'subject2','value':19}];

let cols = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'];
let rows = ['subject1', 'subject2'];

let matrix = Array(rows.length).fill().map(() => Array(cols.length).fill(0));
for(const x of notes) {
    let {note, subject, value} = x;
    matrix[rows.indexOf(subject)][cols.indexOf(note)] = value;
}
console.log(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of couple ways to do it.  One way would be to loop thru `cols` and `rows` using `forEach` and find the matching value in `notes` or return `0` to construct the matrix as follows:

```js
let notes = [
  {'note':'n1','subject':'subject1','value':10},
  {'note':'n3','subject':'subject2','value':19}
]

let cols = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3']
let rows = ['subject1', 'subject2']

let matrix = []

rows.forEach(row => {
  let newRow = []
  cols.forEach(col => {
    newRow.push(notes.find(n => n.note === col && n.subject === row)?.value || 0)
  })
  matrix.push(newRow)
})

console.log(matrix)
```

Another method might be to use `reduce` to loop thru `cols` and `rows` to get your matrix:

```js
let notes = [
  {'note':'n1','subject':'subject1','value':10},
  {'note':'n3','subject':'subject2','value':19}
]

let cols = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3']
let rows = ['subject1', 'subject2']

let matrix = rows.reduce((accRow, row) => {
  accRow.push(cols.reduce((accCol, col) => {
    accCol.push(notes.find(n => n.note === col && n.subject === row)?.value || 0)
    return accCol
  }, []))
  return accRow
}, [])

console.log(matrix)
```